# how to make nginx return nodes return messages?

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx node redirecting to 2 server nodes, but when I sent a wrong http request to nginx, I found the returning messages from nginx are not useful, for example in the below. I just need to see the error messages from server nodes which can be contributed to debugging.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>The page is temporarily unavailable</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #000;
            font-size: 0.9em;
            font-family: sans-serif,helvetica;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        :link {
            color: #c00;
        }
        :visited {
            color: #c00;
        }
        a:hover {
            color: #f50;
        }
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0.6em 2em 0.4em;
            background-color: #294172;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 1.75em;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
        }
        h1 strong {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
        h2 {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #3C6EB4;
            font-size: 1.1em;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #fff;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0.5em;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #294172;
        }
        h3 {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #ff0000;
            padding: 0.5em;
            color: #fff;
        }
        hr {
            display: none;
        }
        .content {
            padding: 1em 5em;
        }
        .alert {
            border: 2px solid #000;
        }
```

I would ask if there exist some configurations in the nginx.conf can achieve the feature. How to config that? thank you

Comment: Do you want to set custom error pages? probably something like this: https://gist.github.com/cbednarski/5149466

Comment: you mean to create nginx-error.conf which is in the same folder with nginx.conf?

Comment: I had tried, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nginx default behaviour is this: Show any response from the upstream (your node process). If absolutely no response is available, show nginx error message.

The message you are seeing looks for me, like your node process timed-out. If it wasnt available, you would see a nginx 500 instead.

So what you want, seeing the node error, should already happen. However, it can not happen if your node process is not even able to provide an error. It looks like this is the case here.

To proceed: Insert some file log statements in your node server code or setup remote step-by-step debugging for your node server to find out what is going on there.

Comment: thank you, let me give you an example. when I send a http request to the nginx node, I saw the error messages like above. But I send the same http request to the node which nginx redirect to, there are error messages like below: {
  "error" : "Unknown exception",
  "errorMessage" : "Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token\n at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@60578e2f[c=554,q=1,[0]=EOF,s=STREAM]; line: 1, column: 514] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])",
  "errorClass" : "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException",
  "host" : null
}

Comment: How long does it take until the error message shows up (try it in a clean incognito browser window, please)?

Comment: no, I used the "curl" command,so it has noting to do with browser. I mean that I want to get the redirecting nodes error messages instead of the above nginx error messages when I send a http request to the nginx node